# Can I use Azure Functions V3 Azure static web API

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-static-web-app

When creating an Azure Static Site using the Blazor settings, you get an option to configure an API.  My repository has an Azure Functions V3 API, and I want to use that.  After making all the definitions, the build and deploy workflow fails.  When I eliminate the api_location setting, the workflow succeeds.

I am pretty sure that the workflow expects a V2 Azure Functions application.

Can I supply a custom build command to build the V3 application?

Will role management work OK with V3?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/apis), a managed API can only use .NET Core 3.1, while V3 is .Net 5 based, so that is probably why the build failed.

Having said that, this document is from May 2020, so this maybe changing soon, hopefully...

Update: After discussing the matter with a Microsoft employee involved with the matter, they informed me that (a) the document is indeed up to date and (b) static apps API will .NET 6 support sometime in November...